# Python OpenCV - one function for template matching

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition, template-matching

I've looked into Template Matching and I understand the concept and have implemented it for my case already, and it works. This is the code given in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html):

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv.imread('mario.png')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('mario_coin.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

Basically what is happening here is that it takes a source image and a template, reads the template and looks for matches on the source image. If it finds a match, it draws a rectangle on the source image.

This works fine for one image, but in my case, I'm going to look for multiple templates in the source and as far as I understand, I'd need to copy all of the code above for every template I'm looking for, and that doesnt seem to be right.

So what I'm looking for is a way to put all of this into one function, so that it writes everything onto my source with one command. I'm sorry if I'm not seeing something obvious here, but I cant think of a way to do this properly. How would you do this?

Comment: Hello, would you please provide feedback for the answer? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First I will make a list of all my image files. Then, I will iterate through all the elements of the list. Now your code will be -

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv.imread('mario.png')
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

list = ['file1.png','file2.png','file3.png']

for image in list:
    template = cv.imread(image,0)
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]

    res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.8
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

But if you want to you use different thresholds and comparison methods for every image for template matching then you can put everything inside the loop in a new function and call that functon by passing your threshold and method.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to test multiple templates against the single image source, I would make a directory for template folder (instead of making list as suggested by VIVEK)

In this template folder, I will keep all my templates.

Also, I will create a folder for source images, where I will keep all the source images.

Lastly, I will create one results folder, where I will store all the source images after testing them (images with a red rectangle)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import os, errno



threshold = 0.8 #set threshold
resultsDirectory = 'results'
sourceDirectory = os.fsencode('sourceImages')
templateDirectory = os.fsencode('templates')
detectedCount = 0


for file in os.listdir(sourceDirectory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"): 

        print (filename)

        img_rgb = cv2.imread('sourceImages/'+filename)
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        for templateFile in os.listdir(templateDirectory):
            templateFilename = os.fsdecode(templateFile)

            if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
                template = cv2.imread('templates/'+templateFilename,0)
                w, h = template.shape[::-1]
                res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
                loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

                if (len(loc[0])):
                    detectedCount = detectedCount + 1
                    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
                    cv2.imwrite(resultsDirectory+'/res_'+filename+'.png',img_rgb)
                    print ('/res_'+filename+'.png'+' saved')
                    # break

        print ('detected positive ' + str(detectedCount))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

So, Put the above code in template_matching.py
Other folders will be in the root directory with this file.
Make folder structure like below.

```
Template_Matching
-template_matching.py

-results

-sourceImages
 -source_image.png

-templates
 -template_1.png
 -template_2.png
 -template_3.png
```

You can also use this to check multiple source images against multiple templates.
Just run `py template_matching.py` and see the magic.