# finding and organizing images in one folder using template matching python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

i'm making an nft project i made 40000 images so i want to sort them in folders according to certain objects in certain image
i'm using template image than i want to copy all images that have the same obejct of the template to a new folder
i found opencv template matching
here is exmaples of images, i want to copy all images with red hat that match with template image  to a new folder
[here is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiCB5.png)

here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import os, errno



threshold = 0.8 #set threshold
resultsDirectory = 'results'
sourceDirectory = os.fsencode(r'C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (2)\rrr')
templateDirectory = os.fsencode(r'C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (2)\3.png')
detectedCount = 0


for file in os.listdir(sourceDirectory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"): 

        print (filename)

        img_rgb = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (2)\rrr'+filename)
        img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        for templateFile in os.listdir(templateDirectory):
            templateFilename = os.fsdecode(templateFile)

            if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
                template = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Nouveau dossier (2)\3.png'+templateFilename,0)
                w, h = template.shape[::-1]
                res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
                loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

                if (len(loc[0])):
                    detectedCount = detectedCount + 1
                    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
                        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
                    cv2.imwrite(resultsDirectory+'/res_'+filename+'.png',img_rgb)
                    print ('/res_'+filename+'.png'+' saved')
                    # break

        print ('detected positive ' + str(detectedCount))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: So is there a question?  Does something not work in your code?  Note that basic template matching is not rotationally or scale invariant. That means it will fail if the template and object are not the same scale and orientation. Also if your template background is not transparent and you do not make a mask from the transparency, then your template matching willl not be accurate and mail simply fail.

Comment: sorry i forget to form a question , yes of course there is a probleme my code don't work i don't where is the issue i found this methode in this website but id didn't find the images (sorry i'm not good with python opencv ) and yes the template background us transparent .SO please can you only guide me .

Comment: here is we have the same issue and i tried the given solution but it don't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590190/python-opencv-one-function-for-template-matching

Comment: That solution does not use a mask from the template transparency. Look at the documentation for matchTemplate() regarding using a mask image. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693430/opencv2-matchtemplate-does-not-work-on-different-pictures-with-same-template/68694827#68694827 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71149319/i-cant-get-matchtemplate-in-opencv-to-work/71150667#71150667

Comment: Post your template and object images separately. I cannot tell if its scale is the same as the scale of the hats in your object images. If they are not the same, then your approach will not work. You would need multi-scale template matching.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: luckily, this nft shite will have burned in a great fire, before you're finished comparing 40k images using matchTemplate() (which sounds like totally the wrong way to do)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a fast enough algorithm of nomalized cross correlation, and I just implemented it using OpenCV. [github link](https://github.com/DennisLiu1993/Fastest_Image_Pattern_Matching)

Although it is implemented by c++, all you can find all corresponded opencv functions in python version.

Effects:
[image]

You can use the function Match () to find objects in inspection images, and get the rotation angle and pixel position. You then can use the pixel position to sort all images.

The whole version is too long to be posted here, please check on my github.

Part of the code is as followed:

```
int iSize = (int)vecAngles.size ();
vector<s_MatchParameter> vecMatchParameter (iSize * (m_iMaxPos + MATCH_CANDIDATE_NUM));

for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
{
    Mat matRotatedSrc, matR = getRotationMatrix2D (ptCenter, vecAngles[i], 1);
    Mat matResult;
    Point ptMaxLoc;
    double dValue, dMaxVal;
    double dRotate = clock ();
    Size sizeBest = GetBestRotationSize (vecMatSrcPyr[iTopLayer].size (), pTemplData->vecPyramid[iTopLayer].size (), vecAngles[i]);
    float fTranslationX = (sizeBest.width - 1) / 2.0f - ptCenter.x;
    float fTranslationY = (sizeBest.height - 1) / 2.0f - ptCenter.y;
    matR.at<double> (0, 2) += fTranslationX;
    matR.at<double> (1, 2) += fTranslationY;
    warpAffine (vecMatSrcPyr[iTopLayer], matRotatedSrc, matR, sizeBest);


    MatchTemplate (matRotatedSrc, pTemplData, matResult, iTopLayer);

    minMaxLoc (matResult, 0, &dMaxVal, 0, &ptMaxLoc);

    vecMatchParameter[i * (m_iMaxPos + MATCH_CANDIDATE_NUM)] = s_MatchParameter (Point2f (ptMaxLoc.x - fTranslationX, ptMaxLoc.y - fTranslationY), dMaxVal, vecAngles[i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < m_iMaxPos + MATCH_CANDIDATE_NUM - 1; j++)
    {
        ptMaxLoc = GetNextMaxLoc (matResult, ptMaxLoc, -1, pTemplData->vecPyramid[iTopLayer].cols, pTemplData->vecPyramid[iTopLayer].rows, dValue, m_dMaxOverlap);
        vecMatchParameter[i * (m_iMaxPos + MATCH_CANDIDATE_NUM) + j + 1] = s_MatchParameter (Point2f (ptMaxLoc.x - fTranslationX, ptMaxLoc.y - fTranslationY), dValue, vecAngles[i]);
    }
}
FilterWithScore (&vecMatchParameter, m_dScore-0.05*iTopLayer);
```